# Make a div fill the remaining vertical space in a column using display: flex

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

How can I make a div fill up the remaining vertical space using `display: flex`?

In my example below, the `main` element should fill up all space not used by the nav. If this worked correctly, we wouldn't see any red.

http://jsfiddle.net/36r3mL36/

HTML:

```
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    background: orange;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `html` next to your `body` selector.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, I would suggest to put the flex stuff inside a container.

```css
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: red;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    background: orange;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav></nav>
  <main></main>
</div>
```